# Ionic 2 RC3 iOS 8 custom font letter spacing issue

Tags: ios, iphone, ionic2

I'm creating an Ionic 2 application for use on Android and IOS.  I'm having a real issue with the ios version which is for some reason setting the letter spacing of any and all ion-list items to .1rem which is pretty damn wide so it appears I'm getting this sort of output everywhere there is text being displayed.

W  E  L  C  O  M  E

I've tried setting in the app.scss file

```
*{ 
font-family: 'bebas';
font-size: 20px; 
text-transform:uppercase; 
letter-spacing:normal !important;
}
```

to combat this but the app is ignoring it and still defaults to .1rem which is not ideal.

Has anyone else had this issue? or could suggest a solution as I'm pretty stumped as the app when loaded in safari on a desktop looks fine and it does so in chrome and on android as well.

Many thanks.

Comment: A possible workaround (not the solution) would be to add a style to the `html` tag when the platform is `iOS`. `rem` is relative to the root's font-size, so maybe changing `html {letter-spacing: 2%;}` would work out (not sure)

Comment: I've tried this so far with no luck, ionic seems to be completely ignoring everything I'm entering in app.scss with regards to letter spacing on ios devices.

Comment: I think this issue could be because I failed to set font-weight when setting up the font-face in app.scss.

I think this due to an issue with Safari Mobile treating fonts without a font-weight set as faux bold.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so I found a work around for this issue with custom fonts.  The problem is that on ios the css class platform-webview has the text-rendering property set to optimizeLegibility which causes odd letter spacing in the application.  So in order to fix this I overwrite the class in my app.scss to combat this.

```
body.platform-ios.platform-cordova.platform-webview {
    text-rendering: auto !important;
}
```

I have also tested this workaround with my android version of the application and it seems to work as before with no difference for android.